# Wraping of two dimensional point set

Tags: java, r, algorithm

I have got a list of points in 2-dimension.

For example:

> x=c(4,3,3,5,6,6,4)

and

> y=c(5,3,1,0,1,3,5)

Plot of these 2-D points is

[image]

I would like to draw a wrapper of this point set like this :

[image]

Note that, the perpendicular distance between the boundary(wrapper) and the nearest point is 2 unit.

**Note that**: I have a number of point sets like the above point set. I would like to do the same thing for all the sets.

I want to have this boundary polygon. Could anyone please suggest me how to do this.

Any ideas greatly appreciated, Janak.

Comment: Can the point coordinates be arbitrary floating point values? Is it guaranteed that the result will be a single coherent polygon, without "holes"?

Comment: @laune..sorry for replying late. For both the questions you raised, the answer is yes (points coordinates are arbitrary floating points and single coherent polygon without holes). Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are asking. Are you asking for an algorithm to produce the boundary from the set of points or to move the points away from a given boundary?

Comment: I'm trying - this may have holes. Compute the set of squares, the set of their corner points is C. Compute all intersection rectangles, the set of their corner points is R. Clearly, the points of your polygon must be a subset of U(C, R). - To construct the path, start with a square with max. y coordinates. A vertical side may or may not intersect: if it does, find the closest intersection point and the square causing it; if not, turn at the corner and proceed along that side. Continue until you reach the first square.

Comment: Some care may be necessary with floating point coordinates. Convert to long by scaling (*1000000) and back may be an option.

Comment: @ sprinter...I would like to have a algorithm to produce the boundary from the set of points.

Comment: Do you want the polygon enclosing the *smallest possible area*? Or something close but not minimal?

Comment: @laune....I want polygon which encloses all the points and each side of the polygon are 2 unit away from the closest point. Yes this polygon encloses the smallest possible area (including this 2 unit).

Comment: Then the proposed solution based on rectangles enclosing the center and each point will not be correct.

Comment: @laune... Could you please explain a little bit why it is not correct.

Comment: What language do you want?  You have the `r` tag but do not appear to call for that language.

Comment: Take the points (0,0),(2,2),(4,4),(6,6): center is (3,3) and the rectangles (x,y,w,h) that cover all will be (-2,-2,5,5), (0,0,4,4), (2,2,6,6) (3,3,5,5). First and last of these squares are too big, e.g. the point (-2,5) should not be part of the polygon border.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft...I am more comfortable with R so I tagged R. It would be nice if I have an algorithm for this task in R. But it's ok if I could have the code in other language also.

Comment: Thanks @laune I understand your point.

Comment: @janak So I got around to researching this - see my answer.

Comment: @laune If you give me permission, I would like to have some suggestion  from you regarding the  following issue which is a particular case of the above question and I think can be answerable from the answer given by you . This issue arises when I was researching with this (latitude, longitude) data in more depth. Remember,  we were first constructing the  enclosing grid from a given location of point and then found the boundary polygon. After some research I understood that I should also consider the the direction of the square (instead of whose sides are parallel to one of X or Y  axis).

Comment: I already solved the problem of construction of the grids in a given direction (by using some more information from the locations of the neighbourhood grids). So now I have all four vertices location of  a rectangular grids. I need to find out the boundary polygon constracted by the cluster of neighbouring grids. Could you please provide some suggestion how to do it by modifying the previous answer to the above question?  I gratefully appreciate you help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say or do. In particular "direction of the square" (a square has no "direction"); "I have all four vertices location..." (grammar); "cluster of neighbouring grids" (how would these be defined in terms of the grids/squares defined by the points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java, this becomes very simple. The program demonstrates the result by plotting it. The outline may also be obtained by iterating the `area.getPathIterator(at)`, which will return all points, one by one.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PointSet {
public static final int W = 2;
Area area = new Area();

public void add( double x, double y ){
    area.add( new Area( new Rectangle2D.Double( x-W, y-W,2*W, 2*W ) ) );
}
public void plot(){
    Board board = new Board();
    board.go( area );
}
public static void main( String[] args ){
    PointSet ps = new PointSet();
    ps.add( 4, 5);
    ps.add( 3, 3);
    ps.add( 3, 1);
    ps.add( 5, 0);
    ps.add( 6, 1);
    ps.add( 6, 3);
    ps.plot();
}
}
```

and:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Board extends JPanel {
Area area;
void go( Area area ) {
    this.area = area;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Test");
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    repaint();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
  at.translate( 100, 100 );
  at.scale( 50, 50 );
  PathIterator pit = area.getPathIterator( at );
  Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
  path.append( pit, true );
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
  g2d.draw( path );
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks laune. I greatly appreciate your effort. I shall catch you soon with the results.

Comment: Hi laune I tried to run  your code, but it is giving error and I could not sort it out. Could you please check it.

Comment: What error did you get? Did you change anything? - It runs cleanly on my system, JDK 1.8, but should also with 1.7 or 1.6.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6, Eclipse in ubunto 14.10. The error showing for the first part of the program is :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at day1.PointSet.main(PointSet.java:14)

Comment: You have inserted imports - so what line is this and how does it look. It's a compilation problem - chances are you mistyped.

Comment: I just copied it, pasted in the console and added nothing.  I could not get your point.

Comment: I don't know what line 14 is in *your* Eclipse. Why do you keep stalling - simply copy-paste this line (and the one before and after) and mark it. And you should see a compile error. What is the message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69068/discussion-between-janak-and-laune).

Comment: @janak Final note: changed parameter types from int to double in add method of PointSet. cu

Comment: Hi @laune, I am facing a problem while doing the same task for the below point set. These are on locations (Longitude and Latitude) of some point. Data: (88.56630, 21.03517); ( 88.62501, 21.01287 ); ( 88.60013, 21.05434 ); ( 88.57499, 21.09610 ); ( 88.65879, 21.03207 ); ( 88.63392, 21.07354 ); ( 88.60879, 21.11531 );

Comment: Here our "W" is =0.05 unit. I am actually working with this type of data. So I am facing the following questions: First: how to introduce Earth distance (instead of Euclidean distance) in the above program? Second: How to plot appropriately the polygon corresponding to the above data (it going outside the screen)? I think here we need a automatic selection of scale parameter from the range of the given data points. Third: How to print the corner points of the polygon in a orderly manner? Could you please kindly help me to solve these issues.

Comment: Hi @laune I posted the descriptions about the problems.

Comment: Using spheric geometry: if W meant to be a distance in degrees, you get the true outline, in the sense that the corners are so many minutes and seconds away from the point. If you want true distance, you'll have to define W in meters.

Comment: That's OK, we can meet.

Comment: Hi @laune are you there?

Comment: Not much time now.  You use area.getPathIterator() and you use the API of PathIterator: isDone, currentSegment, next. Read the javadoc!

Comment: I am clarifying and correcting the points that you mentioned. 1) By direction of square I mean the slope of one edge of the square grid. 2) Correcting: "I have location of all four vertices of a grid\square. 3) Our goal is to find out the outline polygon formed by the boundary edges of the cluster ( this cluster is formed by the some neighbouring grids).

Comment: Here is the room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70360/janak-and-laune I'll be there around 8:00, 9:00, 10:000 UTC

Comment: Thanks for the response. This time is fine for me, I shall be in the chat room at that time (8 am, 9am, 10 am UTC, Friday). See you there.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use this simple algorithm.
First we will need the **center of your coordinates (red dot)**.
This can be done by adding all of your x-values and divide the result by their amount, same with the y-values.

The next step will be to calculate a **rectange which wraps a current coordinate and the center** point. (Don't forget to add your offset of 2 units here)

[image: First wrapping rectangle]

We will **do this for all coordinates**

[image]

At this point we could already stop. Just render all of those rectangles and then your coordinates on top of the picture, but let's improve this just a little bit more.
We don't actually need all those rectangles, what we want is a polygon to wrap those points.
This polygon is defined by the intersection of our retangles and their edges (blue dots).

[image]

Note that we will only need the edges and intersections which are the furthest away from our center.

We now can connect those blue points by connecting points who share one common coordinate and are 'neighbours'.

[image]

**Update:**

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PolyWrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //your example coords:
        int[] x_coords = {4,3,3,5,6,6,4};
        int[] y_coords = {5,3,1,0,1,3,5};       

        //make sure the coordinates have the same length, else they won't match
        if(x_coords.length != y_coords.length){
            System.err.println("Bad parameters given. X and Y don't match!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //this will hold our points:
        ArrayList<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < x_coords.length; i++){
            Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(x_coords[i], y_coords[i]);
            points.add(p);
        }
        //lets get the center of all those points:
        final Point2D center = get_center(points);
        ArrayList<Rectangle2D> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();

        //now lets create those wrapping rectangles:
        for(Point2D p : points){
            Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double();
            r.setFrameFromDiagonal(center, p);
            rectangles.add(r);
        }

        //now show the wrapping rectangles:
        for(Rectangle2D r : rectangles){
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }


    }

    //this method returns the center of a list of points
    public static Point2D get_center(ArrayList<Point2D> points){
        double x = 0,y =0;
        for(Point2D p : points){
            x += p.getX();
            y += p.getY();
        }
        x = x / points.size();
        y = y / points.size();
        Point2D c = new Point2D.Double();
        c.setLocation(x, y);
        return c;
    }
}
```

So here is some example code. I have not found the time to finish it yet, but since your question is really interesting I will keep working on this. 
So far this code calculates the center-point and creates rectangles around the center and given coordinates. 

 This output provides the upper left corner of each rectangle, it's width and height. 
Sample output:

```
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=4.0,y=2.5714285714285716,w=0.4285714285714288,h=2.4285714285714284]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=3.0,y=2.5714285714285716,w=1.4285714285714288,h=0.4285714285714284]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=3.0,y=1.0,w=1.4285714285714288,h=1.5714285714285716]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=4.428571428571429,y=0.0,w=0.5714285714285712,h=2.5714285714285716]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=4.428571428571429,y=1.0,w=1.5714285714285712,h=1.5714285714285716]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=4.428571428571429,y=2.5714285714285716,w=1.5714285714285712,h=0.4285714285714284]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=4.0,y=2.5714285714285716,w=0.4285714285714288,h=2.4285714285714284]
```

P.s.:
I tried to improve the algorithm from this point but encountered a problem which seems to be hard to solve - Maybe I will start a new question about this problem. 
(It is about the picture with the blue dots. Once you have all points from the rectangles and their intersections it is hard to find out which of the resulting points are actually necessary for our polygon). I think I am close to a solution, so watch out for my next edits.

Comment: Thanks Tim for this great effort to give a solution to my problem. I am looking forward for the solution JAVA code, but there is no hurry, you could do when you have time. Best wishes for your exam.

Comment: Could you check if I am right or not using your JAVA code. Suppose we take points as (1,2); (2,5) and (3,2)and then the center is (3,3). But here finding the boundary of the above type may not possible by using your arguments.

Comment: Hey janak, I am sorry but my code isn't finished yet I got all the rectangles and will work on getting rid of those additional points as soon as possible. I hope to finish it by tonight. The centre of those points would be (2,3) and the boundary of the above point (2,5) would be a special case on which I stumbled writing this algorithm aswell. The solution is to add the margin of 2 units which you described in order to find a wrapping rectangle. This rectangle would have the width of 2*margin (I really hope I got your question right but I am in a bit of a hurry right now).

Comment: Hi Tim I run your code. It is running fine and I understand the issue that you mentioned. Looking forward your next edits to the code addressing this issue.

Comment: @TimHallyburton There is a major flaw in your approach. It is possible to have sets of points that create an overlapping set of squares resulting in a shape that would be enlarged by the construction of the rectangles encompassing the square and the "red center". Even the simple set (0,0);(2,2);(4,4);(6,6); is sufficient since both squares at either end are enlarged to include (3,3), the "red center".