# Wraping of equispaced point set in a given direction

Tags: java, r, algorithm, geospatial, graph-algorithm

Let us consider a 2-D (latitude, longitude) point set. The points in the set are equispaced (approx.) with mutual distance 0.1 degree \times 0.1 degree . Each point in the set is the centre of a square grid of side length 0.1 degree (i.e., intersect point of two diagonals of the square). Each square is adjacent to the neighbouring squares.

Our **goal** is to get the coordinates of the **outline polygon** formed by the bounding sides of the square grids with  given direction (will be illustrated with a figure). This polygon has **no hole** inside.

Let us  consider a sample data set of size 10 (point set).

```
lat_x <- c(21.00749, 21.02675, 21.00396, 21.04602, 21.02317, 
           21.06524, 21.00008, 21.04247, 21.08454, 21.0192)
```

and

```
lon_y <- c(88.21993, 88.25369, 88.31292, 88.28740, 88.34669, 
           88.32118, 88.40608, 88.38045, 88.35494, 88.43984)
```

Here is the rough plot of the above points followed by some illustration, [image]

The black points are the (lat,lon) points in the above sample.

The blue square boxes are the square grid.

The given directions (\theta) of the squares are $theta$=50 degree.

Our goal is to get the ordered (clockwise or counter clockwise) co-ordinates of the outline polygon (in yellow colour).

**Note:** This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27897918/wraping-of-two-dimensional-point-set) with a nice answer given by @laune. There the goal is to get the outline polygon without direction (or 0 degree direction). But in the the present set up I need to include the direction (non-zero) while drawing the square grids and the resulted polygon.

I would gratefully appreciate any suggestion, java or R codes or helpful reference given by anyone solving the above problem.

Comment: Do you know where the center of rotation is? I'm assuming it's not from 0,0. And will you know theta ahead of time or is that something you have to estimate. Seems like the best thing to do would be to un-rotate it 50 deg, use the other others, and then translate those points by rotating them back.

Comment: Midpoints appear to be on the bounding lines, build up from there....

Comment: @MrFlick These are satellite data and the $theta$ is estimated by observing the direction of the travel pass of the satellite. Rotation and translation may not be good idea because  points are on (lat,lon) and the geo-distance between two points is not invariant of the translation and the rotation of the points.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't  know exactly where is  the centre of rotation. Sorry for late reply and thanks for your attention.

Comment: @John Thanks for attention.  Could please explain how I can start the construction from midpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

[image: grid outline]

1. **may be some 2D array point grouping to match the grid**

   that should speed up all the following operations.
2. **compute average grid sizes (img1 from left)**

   as two vectors
3. **create blue points (img2)**

   as: `gray_point (+/-) 0.5*blue_vector`
4. **create red points (img3)**

   as: `blue_point (+/-) 0.5*red_vector`
5. **create list of gray lines (img4)**

   take all 2 original (gray) points that have distance close to average grid distance and add line for them
6. **create list of red lines (img4)**

   take all 2 original (gray) points that have distance close to average grid distance and add line for them if it is not intersecting any line from gray lines
7. **reorder line points to match polygon winding ...**
8. **angle**

compute angle of red vector (via atan2)

compute angle of blue vector (via atan2)

return the one with smaller absolute value

**[edit1] response to comments**

**grid size**

find few points that are closest to each other so pick any point and find all closest points to it. The possible distances should be near:

```
sqrt(1.0)*d,sqrt(1+1)*d,sqrt(1+2)*d,sqrt(2+2)*d,...
```

where `d` is the grid size so compute `d` for few picked points. Remember the first smallest `d` found and throw away all that are not similar to smallest one. Make average of them and let call it `d`

**grid vectors**

Take any point `A` and find closest point `B` to it with distance near `d`. For example `+/-10%` comparison: `|(|A-B|-d)|<=0.1*d` Now the grid vector is `(B-A)`. Find few of them (picking different `A,B`) and group them by sign of `x,y` coordinates into 4 groups.

Then join negative direction groups together by negating one group vectors so you will have 2 list of vectors (red,blue direction) and make average vectors from them (red,blue vectors)

**shifting points**

You take any point `A` and add or substract half of red or blue **vector** to it (not its size!!!) for example:

```
A.x+=0.5*red_vector.x;
A.y+=0.5*red_vector.y;
```

**line lists**

Make 2 nested `for`s per each 2 point combination `A,B` (original for gray lines,shifted red ones for red outline lines) and add condition for distance

```
|(|A-B|-d)|<=0.1*d
```

if it is `true` add line `(A,B)` to the list. Here pseudo C++ example:

```
    int i,j,N=?;       // N is number of input points in pnt[]
    double x,y,d=?,dd=d*d,de=0.1*d; // d is the avg grid size
    double pnt[N][2]=?;    // your 2D points
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)      // i - all points
     for (j=i+1;j<N;j++)   // j - just the rest no need to test already tested combinations
       {
       x=pnt[i][0]-pnt[j][0];
       y=pnt[i][1]-pnt[j][1];
       if (fabs((x*x)+(y*y)-dd)<=de) ... // add line pnt[i],pnt[j] to the list...
       }
```

Comment: Thanks @Spektre  for your attention and efforts. Could you please explain a little bit on the following issues in your proposed algorithm: (Point 2) To find the average  grid sizes, what are the choices of the vectors? Is it the 2-D point itself?  (Point 5) How to get the blue and red points? Note that here substituting or adding 0.05 unit to the point coordinate and getting the corner points of the square grid as those deviated points will not help because it will not consider the direction in which point should move.

Comment: Also I did not get your 6th point and what is grid distance?  Could you please explain a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Sorry for late reply...I was trying to code the given algorithm. I stuck here, in the grid vector part, after getting the 4 groups you commented "join negative direction groups together by negating one group vectors". Here, what are the negative direction group? Do you mean those with two co-ordinates are negative or those with atleast one coordinate negative! I am trying to code this in R.

Comment: @janak you should have 4 direction from which 2 are opposite to each other so if you negate vector from one group you get the direction of the other group. By negating I mean multiply by -1 all coordinates ... (it is similar to North is negative to South, West is negative to East) ... your vectors are rotated so you need handle all as vectors not by single coordinates ... (you should check out vector math basics)